# Can we do grep and sed from a file and push the output into a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Trying to do grep and sed from a file and push the output into a variable

```
grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed '{'s/=.*//'}'
```

Output would be like this:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001ef50fcb0f778b86-part3
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3644a8420420897001ef50fcb0f778b86-part2
```

Error:

```
[/~]# grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'} >> $x
-bash: $x: ambiguous redirect
```

if i do this

```
x=`grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'}`
```

or

```
x=$(grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'})
```

I get :

```
[root@localhost ~]# $x
-bash: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-4644a8420420897001f2af8cc054d33bb: No such file or directory
```

Somehow, it is trying to resolve the disk path.

Can we push all 3 lines into a variable?
Thanks!

Comment: `$x` will run the lines stored in the variables as _separate_ commands. You need to use `echo` or `printf` to store the output of the variable to the console. Do `echo "$x"` or `printf "%s\n" "$x"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line does push the values to the variable.

`x=$(grep "^/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-*" /tmp/disks.txt | sed {'s/=.*//'})`

But `$x` will execute each line in the x. Try `echo $x` to get the output of all the line stored in the variable. Although not a good idea to store multiple line in a variable as there are chances of garbling of end line characters, you can also try to store the output to a file and read it. This will save you formattign related errors.